# How to save Image with its original size?

Tags: apache-flex

In my Flex application I load an image into the Image control. After loading the image I can apply filters like color transform or grayscale etc and then I want to save the image with the filter applied. I am having trouble saving the image with the filters applied. With the following code the Image gets saved without the filters. However, if I use

> finalImagedata =
>   ImageSnapshot.captureBitmapData(myImage);

Then the image gets saved with filters applied but with the dimension of the image control. I want to save the image with its original dimension. To be clear, if the image is 1000px X 1000px and displayed in a 300px X 300px image control, while saving I still want to save the image with 1000px X 1000px dimesnion. How to do that? I have also tried to get BitmapData directly from the image control content like below but that doesn't seemt to work. Any help guys?

> finalImagedata =
>   Bitmap(myImage.content).bitmapData;

```
            var filtersArray:Array = new Array;
            private var finalImagedata:BitmapData;

            private function loadImage(url:String):void
            {
                var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest(url);

                var imageLoader:Loader = new Loader();
                imageLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, image_completeHanlder);
                imageLoader.load(request);
            }
            private function image_completeHanlder(event:Event):void
            {
                var bmd:BitmapData = Bitmap(event.currentTarget.content).bitmapData;
                var bmpMy:Bitmap = new Bitmap(bmd);
                myImage.data=bmpMy;

            }
            protected function button1_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
            {
                loadImage("http://localhost/main/image.jpg"); 
            }

            protected function prepareFinalImage():void
            {
                finalImagedata = new BitmapData(myImage.content.width, myImage.content.height, true);
                finalImagedata.draw (myImage.content);
            }
            protected function btnSave_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
            {
                prepareFinalImage();

                var encoder:Object = new Object();
                var defaultName:String;

                        var je:*;
                        je = new JPGEncoder(100);
                        encoder.encode = je.encode;
                        defaultName = "myImage.jpg";


                var imageBytes:ByteArray = encoder.encode(finalImagedata);
                var fr:FileReference = new FileReference();
                fr.save(imageBytes,defaultName);
            }


            protected function btnGrayScale_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
            {
                var red:Number = 0.3086; // luminance contrast value for red
                var green:Number = 0.694; // luminance contrast value for green
                var blue:Number = 0.0820; // luminance contrast value for blue
                var cmf1:ColorMatrixFilter = new ColorMatrixFilter([red, green, blue, 0, 0, red, green, blue, 0, 0, red, green, blue, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0]);
                filtersArray.push(cmf1);
                myImage.filters = filtersArray;
            }
```

Comment: Do you mean "how to save Image with it is original size"? If not, then you should get rid of the apostrophe and write "how to save Image with its original size" instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should store the bitmapdata retrieved from the `Loader` as a class member:

```
private var bmd:BitmapData;
[...]
private function image_completeHanlder(event:Event):void
{
    bmd = Bitmap(event.currentTarget.content).bitmapData;
    var bmpMy:Bitmap = new Bitmap(bmd);
    myImage.data=bmpMy;
}
```

and your `prepareFinalImage` method should rely on the loaded bitmapdata:

```
protected function prepareFinalImage():void
{
    finalImagedata = new BitmapData(bmd.width, bmd.height, true);
    if (myImage.filters.length > 0)
        finalImagedata.applyFilter(bmd, 
            new Rectangle(0, 0, bmd.width, bmd.height), 
            new Point(0,0), myImage.filters[0] as BitmapFilter);
    if (myImage.filters.length > 1)
        for (var i:int = 1; i < myImage.filters.length; i++)
        {
            finalImagedata.applyFilter(finalImagedata, 
                new Rectangle(0, 0, bmd.width, bmd.height), 
                new Point(0,0), myImage.filters[i] as BitmapFilter);
        }
}
```

This way you would apply the filters on the `BitmapData` not on the scaled `DisplayObject`.

Comment: I may be doing something wrong, but I keep getting error "TypeError: Error #2007: Parameter filterObject must be non-null." when I call prepareFinalImage. Even after the filter has been applied.

Comment: You should check whether the cast `myImage.filters[i] as BitmapFilter` is `null`. Applying the exact filters would be better, of course, in order you put them into the array of `myImage.filters`.

Comment: That may have been the problem. The cast is returning null. The workaround I found is to apply the filter directly to the bitmapdata object loaded by the loader and then displaying that in the Image control. This way when I want to save the final image I can save it using that bitmapdata. I am not sure it's the correct way to do it, though.